# Powershell: Select returns empty list

Tags: powershell, select

I have this command:

```
wmic qfe list
```

It returns the installed windows updates. But I only want certain properties to be listed, so I write this (with multiple properties):

```
wmic qfe list | SELECT InstalledOn
```

but it returns an empty list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably because PowerShell is showing a different column name. It's confusing. Have you tried using `Get-HotFix` instead? `Get-HotFix | Select-Object InstalledOn` works fine for me :-)

Comment: `wmic` is an executable, it returns `[string]`'s - and `[string]` doesn't have an `InstalledOn` property :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wmic.exe` isn't a very good tool to use from Windows PowerShell. You'll get a lot further using `Get-WmiObject` (Windows PowerShell only) or `Get-CimInstance` (PS v3.0+ including PS Core).

The pain of switching between the two is knowing what `wmic` alias maps to which WMI/CIM class. Fortunately, you can run a command to tell you what the map is: `wmic alias list brief` returns this:

```
FriendlyName         PWhere                                          Target
------------         ------                                          ------
NICConfig            Where Index=#                                   Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
SysDriver            where Name='#'                                  Select * from Win32_SystemDriver
TapeDrive                                                            Select * from Win32_TapeDrive
NTEventLog           WHERE LogfileName='#'                           Select * from Win32_NTEventlogFile
UserAccount                                                          Select * from Win32_UserAccount
Job                  WHERE jobid=#                                   Select * from Win32_ScheduledJob
SoftwareElement                                                      Select * from Win32_SoftwareElement
Volume               Where DeviceID = '#'                            Select * from Win32_Volume
NetProtocol                                                          Select * from Win32_NetworkProtocol
QuotaSetting                                                         Select * from Win32_QuotaSetting
Group                                                                Select * from Win32_Group
BIOS                                                                 Select * from Win32_BIOS
UPS                                                                  Select * from Win32_UninterruptiblePowerSupply
Server                                                               Select * from Win32_PerfRawData_PerfNet_Server
VolumeUserQuota      Where Account = # and Volume = #                Select * from Win32_VolumeUserQuota
ShadowCopy           Where ID = '#'                                  Select * from Win32_ShadowCopy
RDAccount            Where AccountName = '#' and TerminalName = '#'  Select * from Win32_TSAccount
Port                                                                 Select * from Win32_PortResource
PrinterConfig        WHERE Name='#'                                  Select * from Win32_PrinterConfiguration
Environment                                                          Select * from Win32_Environment
Registry                                                             Select * from Win32_Registry
BootConfig                                                           Select * from Win32_BootConfiguration
DesktopMonitor       WHERE DEVICEID='#'                              Select * from WIN32_DESKTOPMONITOR
QFE                                                                  Select * from Win32_QuickFixEngineering
PrintJob             WHERE JobId=#                                   Select * from Win32_PrintJob
DiskDrive            WHERE Index=#                                   Select * from Win32_DiskDrive
VolumeQuotaSetting   Where Element = # and Setting = #               Select * from Win32_VolumeQuotaSetting
RDToggle             Where ServerName = '#'                          Select * from Win32_TerminalServiceSetting
Startup              where Caption='#'                               Select * from Win32_StartupCommand
OS                                                                   Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem
IRQ                  WHERE IRQNumber=#                               Select * from Win32_IRQResource
Share                WHERE Name='#'                                  Select * from Win32_Share
ComputerSystem                                                       Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem
ShadowStorage        Where DiffVolume = # and Volume = #             Select * from Win32_ShadowStorage
Service              WHERE Name='#'                                  Select * from Win32_Service
RDNIC                Where TerminalName = '#'                        Select * from Win32_TSNetworkAdapterSetting
LOGON                                                                Select * from Win32_LogonSession
NTDOMAIN             WHERE DomainName='#'                            Select * from Win32_NTDomain
RDPermissions        Where TerminalName = '#'                        Select * from Win32_TSPermissionsSetting
PortConnector        WHERE ExternalReferenceDesignator='#'           Select * from Win32_PortConnector
IDECONTROLLER                                                        Select * from Win32_IDEController
MEMCACHE             WHERE DeviceID='#'                              Select * from WIN32_CACHEMEMORY
TimeZone                                                             Select * from Win32_TimeZone
LogicalDisk          WHERE Name='#'                                  Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk
MemoryChip           Where Tag = '#'                                 Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory
SoundDev             WHERE Name='#'                                  Select * from WIN32_SoundDevice
Product              WHERE Name='#'                                  Select * from Win32_Product
DMAChannel           Where DMAChannel=#                              Select * from Win32_DMAChannel
DeviceMemoryAddress                                                  Select * from Win32_DeviceMemoryAddress
FSDir                WHERE Name='#'                                  Select * from Win32_Directory
NIC                  WHERE DeviceID=#                                Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter
Temperature                                                          Select * from Win32_TemperatureProbe
DESKTOP              WHERE Name='#'                                  Select * from WIN32_DESKTOP
DiskQuota                                                            Select * from Win32_DiskQuota
DataFile             Where Name = '#'                                Select * from CIM_DataFile
DCOMAPP              WHERE Name='#'                                  Select * from WIN32_DCOMApplication
Process              WHERE ProcessId='#'                             Select * from Win32_Process
BaseBoard                                                            Select * from Win32_BaseBoard
LoadOrder                                                            Select * from Win32_LoadOrderGroup
PageFileSet                                                          Select * from Win32_PageFileSetting
Partition            WHERE Index=#                                   Select * from Win32_DiskPartition
SysAccount           WHERE Name='#'                                  Select * from Win32_SystemAccount
PageFile                                                             Select * from Win32_PageFileUsage
SystemSlot                                                           Select * from Win32_SystemSlot
SystemEnclosure                                                      Select * from Win32_SystemEnclosure
WMISet                                                               Select * from Win32_WMISetting
Voltage                                                              Select * from Win32_VoltageProbe
RecoverOS                                                            Select * from Win32_OSRecoveryConfiguration
CDROM                Where Drive='#'                                 Select * from Win32_CDROMDrive
NTEvent              WHERE EventType=#                               Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent
Printer              WHERE Name='#'                                  Select * from Win32_Printer
OnBoardDevice                                                        Select * from Win32_OnBoardDevice
SoftwareFeature                                                      Select * from Win32_SoftwareFeature
MemPhysical                                                          Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray
NetUse               WHERE LocalName='#'                             Select * from Win32_NetworkConnection
CPU                  Where DeviceID='#'                              Select * from WIN32_PROCESSOR
Alias                Where FriendlyName = '#'                        Select * from Msft_CliAlias
NetLogin             WHERE Name='#'                                  Select * from Win32_NetworkLoginProfile
NetClient            WHERE Name='#'                                  Select * from WIN32_NetworkClient
SCSICONTROLLER                                                       Select * from Win32_SCSIController
CSProduct                                                            Select * from Win32_ComputerSystemProduct
```

Here we can see that `QFE` maps to `Win32_QuickFixEngineering`.

So, you'll want to try one of these:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_QuickFixEngineering | Select-Object -Property InstalledOn
```

Or:

```
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_QuickFixEngineering | Select-Object -Property InstalledOn
```

You can also use `Get-HotFix` as mentioned in the comments, but that may not 100% match the output. I'm not 100% sure on how the `Get-HotFix` command works, exactly. It may be more comprehensive than the WMI/CIM class.

Comment: works like a charm. thanks for clearly explaining it!

Answer (score 3):

As Mathias points out, `wmic` returns a string, not objects like native PowerShell cmdlets would.  To get around this, you can use `ConvertFrom-String` to make the objects.  By providing the `PropertyNames` parameter, you can name each field as you like.  I named them to match the output provided by `wmic`.  Now you can use select on the output to get the `InstalledOn` property.

```
$properties = Caption,CSName,Description,FixComments,HotFixID,InstallDate,InstalledBy,InstalledOn,Name,ServerPackInEffect,Status

wmic qfe list | ConvertFrom-String -PropertyNames $properties | select InstalledOn
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have some issue with the output of this:

some of the InstalledOn values are blank, and some of the HotFixIDs are changed to 'NT'. I did a screesnhot about how it looks like:
https://imgur.com/Qz534pN

Comment: Some of the InstalledOn values will be blank because they are empty.  It looks like `ConvertFrom-String` doesn't agree with the spaces in the output.  I briefly looked into it, but it looks like using the native PowerShell will be a better (easier) solution.  See the answer by Bacon Bits.